# Hume’s Empiricism and the Possibility of an Epistemology Grounded in Metaphysics

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, hume, empiricism, apriorticity-and-aposteriority

Was epistemology continued in metaphysics? Was the impossibility of an epistemology grounded in metaphysics made impossible by Humean empiricism in the sense that *a posteriori* questions of fact are based on habitual inductions? By confirming the object to the subject does metaphysics become an epistemic possibility?

The motivation for the Kantian critique comes from the impossibility of rationally establishing a structuring of moral praxis, the cause of empirical determinism when Hume's natural habitualism is extended to human behavior.

My question was motivated by a text I transcribed from a Brazilian commentator (unknown):

> The epistemological equivalent of the geocentric hypothesis in
> astronomy, according to Kant, is the assumption that knowledge
> requires the knower to conform his “mental representations” to the
> object being known. If this were the case, then the problem of
> metaphysical knowledge would be insoluble, and Hume's skepticism would
> be inevitable. On this hypothesis all knowledge of the object would
> have to derive from experience, and Kant concedes to Hume's argument
> that experience can offer only provisional inductive generalizations,
> which can never result in the universal and necessary truths required
> by metaphysics.
>
> ```
>  Kant's Copernican initiative was to reject the hypothesis that the subject must conform to the object in favor of the hypothesis that
> ```
>
> the object must conform to the subject. If this were the case, then
> metaphysics would be possible. It would be known of all objects that
> they must have certain necessary traits in order for them to be
> experienced by the subject. These features would then necessarily and
> universally apply to objects of experience, and knowledge of such
> features would qualify as metaphysical. On this hypothesis, therefore,
> the possibility of metaphysical knowledge would be preserved, but
> metaphysics would have to be conducted in a radically new way.
> Dogmatic rationalism, which purports to gain insight into the
> character of actuality, but which has instead revealed only the
> content implicit in its own terms and definitions, would be replaced
> by a rigorous examination of the knower's own capacities for
> understanding. representation and experience. Metaphysical knowledge
> of the experience of objects depends on knowledge of these capacities,
> because it is to them that such objects must conform.

”

Comment: You might want to narrow it down to one major question and then provide some explanation of the question. For instance, how your experience and thinking progressed to get you wonder why metaphysical epistemology is impossible. I'm not sure it's clear what you mean by metaphysical epistemology, etc. Metaphysics is about the ultimate nature of things, and epistemology is the study of knowledge broadly conceived. You seem to be getting at an intersection.

Comment: @JD Done modifit

Comment: I'm guessing this is another homework problem.

Comment: @DavidGudemanI study mathematics, not philosophy. It's a genuine question

Comment: Almost! One more step, just one more! @DavidGudeman, a homework question? Splendid!

Comment: "Impossibility of rationally establishing a structuring of moral praxis, the cause of empirical determinism when Hume's natural habitualism is extended to human behavior". Can you spell out what this is supposed to mean without "moral praxis", "empirical determinism" and "natural habitualism"? If this means that Kant wanted to save morality in the face of Hume's skepticism then yes, it was part of his motivation. But only a part and not the part featured in the first critique. There he is more concerned with saving mathematics and "pure" physics.